# Spark Dataframes Queries

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to use **DataFrames as criteria**?

Like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.table("Table")
df.select("Column1").filter("Column2").equals("String")
df.filter("Column3").ne("String")
```

Comment: is this because you have invalid DFs with mixed types in a single column? Because otherwise you shouldn't have multiple types in a single column -> this sort of queries would either filter out all or no records

Comment: If there are multiple types it will simply result in a runtime exception. Not to mention is not that easy to get there.

Comment: the df is loading the entire table, I need to fetch one column based on some conditions on other 2 columns. Not having multiple types in the same column.

Comment: the answwer is of course yes.... but please elaborate... what do you want to do? to you want to filter df1 <some columns> according to values in df2 <columnA> ?? I'm thinking merge here.......

Comment: Ok, I have a table called Demand, I would like to fetch DemandCustomers whose faceValue is recommended and History is not default. So my query would be,
Select DemandCustomer from Demand where faceValue = 'Recommended' and history <> 'default'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you need exactly (the phrasing of the question seems to have confused the responders here), but according to your last comment - how about:

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE faceValue = 'Recommended' AND history <> 'default'")
```

?

Comment: Thanks Tzach and sorry for confusing. I was trying to see if the dataframe queries can be used like hibernate criteria. I have tried as you said, but <> is not working, I'm using 1.5.1 version. I have a work around but I just want to check if there is a way to use the dataframes like hibernate

Comment: OK, i think it started working from 1.6 version of spark, earlier i was using 1.5.